# GraphQL mutations on nested resources

Tags: rest, graphql, graphql-js

Mutations are queries for manipulating data. If so then my `root query` and `root mutation` tree should look similar right? They both should allow nested fields (nested mutations). I was playing with this (using `express-graphql`) and it works.

Example:

```
// PUT /projects/:project_id/products/:id
mutation {
  findProject(id: 1) { // make sure that project exists and we can access it before mutating data
    updateProduct(id: 1, name: "Foo") { // the resolve function receives a valid `project` as the first argument
      id
    }
  } 
}
```

Is this a valid example? Should mutations be nested like this? If no, how should I handle nested resources? I can not find any real-life example that would mutate nested resources. All examples define mutations only on the first level (fields on the root mutation).

Comment: I know you got the answer on GitHub that it's not supported, but I'm curious if you really did give up on this approach or if you stuck with it as it seems to work nevertheless.

Comment: Maybe you can get some inspiration from the nested mutation api in Graphcool: https://www.graph.cool/docs/reference/simple-api/nested-mutations-ubohch8quo/

Answer (score 0):

The product has a unique ID, so that's all you need to identify it.

```
mutation {
  updateProduct(id: 1, name: "Foo") {
    id
  }
}
```

To verify that the user is authorized to modify the product, you should check the products' project. You'd probably have some centralized authorization anyway:

```
resolve({ id }, { user }) {
  authorize(user, 'project', Product.find(id).project) // or whatever

  ... // update
}
```

---

Old answer:

This is certainly a valid example.

I'd guess the lack of nested object mutation examples may be due to the fact that even if a product is linked to a project, it would in most cases still have a unique ID -- so you can find the product even without the project id.

Another alternative would be to include the project id as an argument to `updateProduct`:

```
mutation {
  updateProduct(projectId: 1, id: 1, name: "Foo") {
    id
  }
}
```

Your solution seems nicer to me, though.

---

As a note, mutations are, in fact, exactly the same as queries. The only difference is that the `resolve` function typically includes some permanent change, like modifying some data. Even then though, the mutation behaves just like a query would -- validate args, call resolve function, return data of the declared type.

We declare such method as a mutation (and not a query) to make explicit that some data are going to be changed but also for the more important reason: The order in which you modify data is important. If you declare multiple mutations in one request, the executor will run them sequentially to maintain consistency (this doesn't attempt to solve distributed writes though, that's a whole another problem).

Comment: Well, the author of GraphQL seems to disagree https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/issues/221

Comment: Your suggestion is a dangerous one. Bear in mind the fact that the most important technical difference between queries and mutations, as pointed out in this article (https://medium.com/the-graphqlhub/your-first-graphql-server-3c766ab4f0a2#bee6), is "[...] that mutations are processed serially, but queries make no such guarantee".